# PlaceAutocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener Not Triggering Inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I'm using `SupportPlaceAutoCompleteFragment` inside my map_fragment class as a nested fragment.first i initialized `SupportPlaceAutoCompleteFragment` dynamically and removed it on destroy. but `PlaceAutocompleteFragmentset.OnPlaceSelectedListener` method not working.

below is my code.

Initializing places fragment:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.where_to_refuel_frag, container, false);

        autocompleteFragment = new SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_content, autocompleteFragment);
        ft.commit();

        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), place.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
            }
            });
return rootView;
}
```

frame_layout in xml:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

OnDestroy method:

```
@Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        if (autocompleteFragment != null) {
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.remove(autocompleteFragment).commitNowAllowingStateLoss();
        }
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
```

OnActivityResult:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        autocompleteFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: See this link may help you:https://www.androidtutorialonline.com/onactivityresult-in-fragment/

Comment: Thanks for your help sir. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used the dependency:
com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1
and
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1

Then I made the imports and it worked correctly.

Comment: I have also added that lines. They should be there to work. Can you please show me your code